# Why am I getting SSL_read errors and Rpc_client_frag_read errors when trying to Remote Desktop

Tags: linux, terminal, remote-desktop, gateway, freerdp

I'm trying to set up a remote desktop session for monitoring specific systems at my place of work. I only have access to a Linux machine and I need to connect via a terminal server gateway. I am using FreeRDP to do this and i am using the following command to create the connection:

> xfreerdp /d:** /u:***** /p:******* /g:******.************.***
>   /v:****.*********.***** /port:3389 /size:1920x1080

I have hidden all connection details per my supervisors request however both he and I verified the correct information is entered into the fields.
When I send the connection through I get the following error:

> Connected to ******.************.***:443
>
> Connected to ******.************.***:443
>
> TS Gateway Connection Success
>
> Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and called 7
>
> Got stub length 4 with flags 3 and called 6
>
> SSL_read: I/O error: connection reset by peer (104)
>
> Rpc_client_frag_read: error reading header

Would anyone have any idea of what I might be missing? I have even tried adding

> /sec:rdp

to the script and even that produced the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try rdp from a Windows system (or have someone else try from **their** system, since you don't have direct access to Windows). I know it won't solve your problem, but it may give you better information. I'm in a similar situation and got the same error message. I tried remmina instead of xfreerdp and got even less information than xfreerdp spits out.

From a Windows VM, at least I could tell when I got my domain\username & password right -- it told me my account was not allowed rdp access to that server. I'm figuring that means that there are accounts that can rdp in, but mine is not among them. Along the way, though, I found that the remote was using a certificate from an untrusted authority, which was useful information for my case.

If your Linux is old or hasn't been updated, do so. Your certificate store may be out of date. But it may also be that your company's Windows domain has certificates that Linux doesn't know about. It could be a simple matter that you're lacking the company-supplied cert (because they push it to all Windows machines on the domain, but your Linux machine doesn't get that "benefit").

Comment: I'm allowed RDP, and I can remote in from windows base machines just fine, I remote in at home even. Its just that I need to be able to monitor some system information from my desk at work and the information I need to monitor is on a centralize machine located in the building. And to my misfortune, I am not able to request a new machine and can just use the spare linux machine that they have in my office.